repository 'file:/cdrom noble Release' no longer has a Release file
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04, however after running 'sudo apt update' after installation it gives a strange result:
E: The repository 'file:/cdrom noble Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

I checked the source.list file and the content was:
deb [check-date=no] file:///cdrom noble main restricted

I have no idea what this repository is (I never had such issue on 22.04 or 23.04) and how to fix it!
can someone kindly explain to me, what is the problem with it and how can I fix it?
